# Unable to add <img> inside the <div> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I add the images inside the `<div id = 'book'>....</div>` . Unfourtunely it does not create any img tag as I expected. What is the error?  The paths is confirmed contains value .

```
$('#book').append('<img src ="' + paths[1] + '" style = "width:100%;height:100%;top:1px;left:1px" alt = "flip book" id = "logo-cover" />');
```

Update:

This may due to the path[1] value , it is using for loop to iterate an array
it is possible an empty value, but it should be skipped as i have checked before append...

Whole script

```
    <script>
function load_pages(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scandir.php",
        data: "page=" + page,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i,paths){
                    var status = 'nonFinal';
                    if (paths[0] == '' && i == 'next'){
                        status = 'suspectFinal';
                    }
                    if (paths[1] == '' && i == 'next' && status == 'suspectFinal'){
                        status = 'final';
                        page--;
                        load_pages(page);
                        status == 'nonfinal'
                    }
                    else{
                        if (paths[0] != ''){
                            console.log('method called'); 
                            $('#book').append($('<img>').attr('src',paths[0]).css({'width':'100%','height':'‌​100%','top':1px;}).attr('id','logo-cover'));
                        }

                        if (paths[1] != ''){
                            console.log('method2 called'); 
                            $('#book').append($('<img>').attr('src',paths[1]).css({'width':'100%','height':'‌​100%','top':1px;}).attr('id','logo-cover'));
                        }
                    }
            });
            }
    });
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var inputPage = '1';
    if (inputPage == '1'){
        inputPage = '2';
    }

    load_pages(inputPage);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where and when exactly do you call this piece of code? It looks OK so it might be the case that you call it before #book even exists.

Comment: Use Firebug to tell you the error!

Comment: Just a tip: you can use jQuery to create elements: $('#book').append($('<img>').attr('src',paths[1]) )

Comment: Or open Chrome, hit F12, reload the page and check the Console tab for error messages....

Comment: Unexpected input (line 1) , and line 1 is <!doctype html>....

Comment: The script is after the <div book></div>

Comment: @LeandroBarreto , what about the style tag , is it 'style','.....'?

Comment: Just using a few elements: $('#book').append($('<img>').attr('src',paths[1]).css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','top':'1px'}).attr('id','logo-cover') )

Comment: Now have a error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: @user782104 I think the error is here (second 'if' statement):

status == 'nonfinal'

Comment: Thanks for the remind, it omitt a ; , however, now it return an error of  Unexpected token ;

Comment: Well, besides that, it should be "status = nonfinal;" instead of "status == nonfinal;", since it is assignment of value, not a boolean test.

Comment: yes i have changed it already

Comment: Couple more syntax errors :-), in the else and second if statements, when setting the style, there should be '1px' (with quotes, without the semicolon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code is correct, I used it to create this working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah87q/

You should check if `paths[1]` is not null, or you chould find the error somewhere else.

Comment: Do you realise that the condition "paths[1] != ''" is not enough? for example, paths[1] could be 'undefined' and that's != ''

Answer (score 0):

One method to check if the code is called at all is to add some sort of callback function to the 'append()' method. Although it doesn't have one, we will simulate it this way:

```
$('#book').append('<img src ="' + paths[1] + '" style = "width:100%;height:100%;top:1px;left:1px" alt = "flip book" id = "logo-cover" />').each(function(){ 

console.log('method called'); 
// or with an alert
alert('method called'); 

});
```

If it is not called at all, the problem might be in using id instead of a class ('#' instead of '.') or something similar. Also, this method might be called before the element "#book" has loaded, so you might want to put your code inside the

$(document).ready(function(){

});